# Python Flask Jinja extend html inside another extended html

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a question if this is possible.
I have an layout.html page which is connected to home.html. Inside home.html i have an table element. Iam trying too get the content too the table from table.html.

You can see in the code what i have tried.
Any knowledge if this is even possible?

layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Armering bestilling</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Home.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="card bg-dark">
        <div class="card-header text-white bg-dark mb-3" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn text-light" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    Armering bunnplate
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
             <table class="table table-striped table-dark" align="center">
                <thead>
                  {% extends "table.html" %}
                  {% block content %}
                  {% endblock content %}
              </thead>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

table.html

```
{% block content %}
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>FB1</td>
    <td>001</td>
    <td>00</td>
    <td>STK</td>
    <td>B500NC</td>
    <td>25.0</td>
    <td>20.0</td>
    <td>None</td>
    <td>None</td>
    <td>6575.0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>6.58</td>
</tr>
 {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: did you try running it and see if it works?

Comment: yes i have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Jinja2 only supports one level of inheritance.  You might be able to achieve what you're trying to do using includes.

`layout.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
</body>
```

`child.html`:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
  {% with objects = some_objects %}
    {% include "table.html" %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endblock %}
```

`table.html`:

```
{% for object in objects %}
  {{ object.name }}
  {{ object.desc }}
{% endfor %}
```

This will work when you render the tempate with some code like:

```
d = [ {'name':'a', 'desc':'b'},
      {'name':'c', 'desc':'d'}
    ]
return render_template('child.html', some_objects = d)
```

Additionally if you want to pass multiple variables down, this syntax is valid for the `with` tag:

```
{% with objects = some_objects, title = title %}
```

Tested with `Jinja2==2.10.3`

Answer (score 1):

[Jinja 2.11 now supports nested templating.](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#template-inheritance)

If you aren't on 2.11 and are working on a smaller app I would suggest upgrading Flask by running `pip install Flask --upgrade`.

Then try making your `table.html` a child of `Home.html`

However, if you are keen on using an older version. You'll need to come up with a workaround like others have suggested.